# Swift semi random selection

Tags: swift, random

I want to "randomly" select from a collection in Swift but have certain instances be selected at different frequencies. Currently I am using.

```
let collection: [Int] = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
let random: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(collection.count)))
let selection: Int = collection[random]
```

I need the code to be compliant with Swift 2.0+.

Comment: How is this code not what you need? Is it not Swift 2 compliant?

Comment: Something like this [Generate random numbers with a given distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309556/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution) ?

Comment: Similar code was reviewed here: [Weighted Probability Problem in Swift](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112605/weighted-probability-problem-in-swift).

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to target iOS 9.0 or later, GameplayKit has a great solution called `GKGaussianDistribution`, which lets you generate random numbers in a range where the frequency of each number matches a bell curve like this:

[image: Frequency of Dice Rolls on a D20 with Gaussian Distribution]

To use this, just import `GameplayKit` into your project, then use this code:

```
let distribution = GKGaussianDistribution.d6()
print(distribution.nextInt())
```

That uses a six-sided die, but you can use any range you want. [You might find my tutorial on GameplayKit random number generation useful.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/35/5/shaping-gameplaykit-random-numbers-gkrandomdistribution-gkshuffl)