# how to increase the possibility of getting a specific random object from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, random

Generally, I know that I can get a random element of an array in the following way:

```
var myArray = [x, y, z]
let myArrayLength = UInt32(myArray.count)
let myArrayIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(myArrayLength))
let randomElement = myArray[myArrayIndex]
```

But how can I make the possibility of y being the random element twice the possibility of x and z being the random element thrice the possibility of y?

**UPDATE**

**NB: Where x, y and z are `CGPoint`s**

Comment: You're probably looking for something called "weighted random": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309556/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution

Comment: @TomC I understand Martin R's solution to get the probabilities in the link you provided but not too sure how to apply those probabilities to say, an array of `CGPoint`s in my case.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to rewrite your array like this: `[x,x,y,z]`. Then, the probability of getting x becomes 0.5, the probability of y becomes 0.25 and the probability of z becomes 0.25. Just repeat the symbols with high probability as much as you want, for example `[x, y, y, z, z, z, z]` is good for what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, but how will I manage a scenario that with a large array. I guess this is simpler to implement for smaller arrays.

Comment: This solution works in simple cases. But even for large arrays, you can iterate on your original array `myArray`, and for each element, repeat it multiple times in another array using a nested loop. For a general method, you can refer to the comment of Tom C on your question.