# Swift: Generate random number between multiple ranges

Tags: swift, random, range

I want to generate a random number that can be between

`-3...-8` and `3...8`

I know I could find a roundabout way of doing this by first doing a random integer between 0 and 1 and then picking the range on that:

```
let zeroOrOne = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
if zeroOrOne == 0 {
    randomNum = CGFloat.random(in: -3...-8)
} else {
    randomNum = CGFloat.random(in: 3...8)
}
```

but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: If anything, replace `let zeroOrOne = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)` with `let posOrNeg = Bool.random()`.

Comment: You might also use `let randomNum = CGFloat.random(in: 3...8) * (Bool.random() ? 1 : -1)`

Comment: `let randomNum: CGFloat = .random(in: .random() ?  -8 ... -3 :  3 ... 8)` You can even omit the Bool type

Comment: @LeoDabus ok _that_ is cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [general solution](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Mixtures_of_Distributions) for generating a random integer within several nonoverlapping ranges.

1. Find the number of integers in each range; this is that range's weight (e.g., if each range is a closed interval `[x, y]`, this weight is `(y - x) + 1`).
2. Choose a range randomly according to the ranges' weights (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309556/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution) for how this can be done in Swift).
3. Generate a random integer in the chosen range: `CGFloat.random(in: range)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you want to use `Bool.random`.

One way to write it would be

```
let randomNum = CGFloat.random(in: 3...8) * (Bool.random() ? 1 : -1)
```

or

```
var randomNum = CGFloat.random(in: 3...8)
if Bool.random() {
   randomNum.negate()
}
```

There is no single correct solution.