# How to select a random key from a "frequency map" in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's say we have the following dictionary:

```
let freqs = [
  "Apple": 3823,
  "Banana": 493,
  "Grape": 8329,
  "Orange": 249,
]
```

The total fruit count is 3823+493+8329+249=12894.

I want to write a function to randomly pick a fruit based on the probability. That is, the function should return "Apple" with a probability of 3823/12894, and so on.

I have a very naive solution, which is to construct a very "raw" array with 3823 apples, 493 bananas, etc, and call random element to get the element from the array. But this is obviously a waste of memory.

Comment: Let N = n1 + n2 + n3 + ... . Generate a random number r between 0 and 1. If it's less than or equal to n1/N, output option 1. Otherwise if it's less than or equal to (n1 + n2)/N, then output option 2. Otherwise if r <= (n1 + n2 + n3)/N, then option 3. Otherwise etc etc until you come to the nth option, and you can skip the test because (n1 + n2 + n3 + ...)/N = 1, so just output the last option if the others all fail.

Comment: Related: [Generate random numbers with a given distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30309556/1187415)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common statics problem and you're trying to sample a discrete unnormalized probability distribution given a set of weights

```swift
let totalWeight = freqs.values.reduce(0, +)

var randomWeight = Int.random(in: 0..<totalWeight)
for (element, weight) in freqs {
    randomWeight -= weight
    if randomWeight < 0 {
        return element
    }
}
return nil
```

The `nil` is just to get a return path to the compiler, but it should be mathematically ruled out if I got my fence posts right.  One of the comments suggested a similar solution using floating point math, but I tend to prefer to keep it discrete

Comment: i lost it inside the for loop. Why `if randomWeight < 0`, then the element is the correct element?

Comment: I think this algorithm unfairly penalize elements at the front of the traversal. For example, the first element is skewed towards smaller probability than it supposed to have, because `randomWeight` is less likely to be <0 without helps of earlier elements

Comment: Because it's subtracting the weights off the random number as it goes along.  For the first check it should mentally read "if my random number is in the first bin, if I subtract the value of the first bin then it is negative".  Do the simple case of two bins each of value 1.  If I generate 0, then it chooses the first bin because 0-1 < 0.  If I generate 1, then I choose the second bin because 1-1 >= 0 and (1-1) - 1 < 0.

Comment: @OMGPOP no, it doesn't.  This isn't some algorithm I pulled out of the air.  This is literally textbook discrete sampling.

Comment: ic. the "bin" analogy makes sense. otherwise this code is pretty hard for me. thanks!